# SASS Combining Variables to Form Unit

Tags: css, sass

How would I combine two variables in SASS to form a single unit? The setup is as follows:

```
$font-size: 16;
$font-unit: px;

$base-font-size: {$font-size}{$font-unit} !default;

@if unit($base-font-size) != 'px' { @warn "Parameter must resolve to a value in pixel units."; }
```

This throws a compile error: Invalid CSS after ... expected expression ... was

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$font-size: 16;
$font-unit: 1px;

$base-font-size: $font-size * $font-unit !default;

@if unit($base-font-size) != px { @warn "Parameter must resolve to a value in pixel units."; }
```

Comment: Well, this does work, but for the sake of the original question is it possible to concatenate two variables as defined?

Comment: The original sample is missing the `#`, it should be:  `$base-font-size: #{$font-size}#{$font-unit}`.  However, when you concatenate them like that, you're actually getting a string and calling the unit function on it throws an error:  "16px" is not a number for `unit'.

Comment: cimmanon, you are right, I did leave off the hash sign and was not able to form a string. And yes, the error is due to type mismatch. The question was more of a lead-in to see if such an action was possible. Thanks for a quick reply!

Comment: This answer should be edited, it is not working.